# Oracle: batch of stored procedures

Tags: oracle, batch-file

can I execute a batch of stored procedures via ODBC in Oracle?
The stored procedures have input parameters that I bind using parameter markers.

In SQL Server I have this capability, in DB2 I just have the possibility to do batch inserts/updates but I cannot batch stored procedures from ODBC/C++ code.

It seems that batching of insert statements is supported in Oracle and also batching of stored procedure is possible if using JDBC.

Is it possible to do same thing but using calls to stored procedures and ODBC?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be- Yes. You can schedule and run jobs using Oracle scheduler. Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/scheduse.htm) for more.

It can be done something like below

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'update_sales',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'OPS.SALES_PKG.UPDATE_SALES_SUMMARY',
   start_date         =>  '28-APR-08 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2', /* every other day */
   end_date           =>  '20-NOV-08 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
   auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
   job_class          =>  'batch_update_jobs',
   comments           =>  'My new job');
END;
/
```

Comment: sorry this is not what I meant. I'd like to execute a batch of Oracle stored procedures from C++ code, dynamically binding the parameters.